# What does mol L−1 mean?

Tags: concentration, mole, units

I am researching how to Determination of Vitamin C Concentration by Titration for my science fair project and it says

> Titrate the sample with $0.005~\mathrm{mol~L^{−1}}$ iodine solution. The endpoint of the titration is identified as the first
>   permanent trace of a dark blue-black color due to
>   the starch-iodine complex.

Does this mean to add iodine until it turns dark blue-black color?

What does $\mathrm{mol ~L^{−1}}$ mean?

Comment: Please have a look at [molar concentration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_concentration).

Answer (score 5):

The units are mole per liter. $\mathrm{mol \times L^{-1}}$ is more conveniently written $\mathrm{mol/L}$. This set of units is referred to as *molarity*, and is a common measure of concentration for a solute dissolved in a solvent. The *solute* may be a solid (ionic or covalent), a gas or a liquid, but is commonly a solid. The *solvent* may be a gas or liquid, but is commonly a liquid. Together, the solute and the solvent form a *solution*.

Specifically, molarity is defined as

$$\text{Molarity} = \frac{\text{mol of solute}}{\text{L of solution}}$$

Note that the volume is of the total solution, not simply the solvent. In a dilute aqueous solution (a small amount of something dissolved in water), we may approximate the solution volume as simply the volume of solvent.